# VPS https and redirect for domain

Tags: ssl, security, https, vps, certificate

I recently bought a vps ( apache + ubuntu) and created ssl-certificates for my domain by using `acme.sh --issue --dns -d example.com -d www.example.com` and got them. But for my domain I want https to be activated and a redirect to https.
This is my VH configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName cihanbatasul.com
    ServerAlias www.cihanbatasul.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well\-known/acme\-challenge/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
    #Redirect permanent / https://cihanbatasul.com              
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName cihanbatasul.com
    ServerAlias www.cihanbatasul.com
    SSLEngine on

    # curl https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/ffdhe2048.txt >> /path/to/signed_cert_and_intermediate_certs_and_dhparams
    SSLCertificateFile      /root/.acme.sh/cihanbatasul.com_ecc/fullchain.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /root/.acme.sh/cihanbatasul.com_ecc/cihanbatasul.com.key

    # enable HTTP/2, if available
    Protocols h2 http/1.1

    # HTTP Strict Transport Security (mod_headers is required) (63072000 seconds)
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000"

</VirtualHost>
```

The warning on my page:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ta8U.png)

I tried using the RedirectRule tag but that didn't work.
I would appreciate some help.
Thank you!

Edit:
My goal with buying this vps was to host my backend application on it and make a call to it on my frontend. My frontend is hosted on godaddys hosting service. I put the backend in a docker container and let it run on my vps on port 8080. It is a simple rest api https server that has one endpoint that sends an email to me when someone fills out the contact formular on my fronten. But for that to work it needs to be a https site. Right now I get the error in my console:

```
index-HS5-14da.js:48 
        
        
       POST https://92.205.185.35:8080/email/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
r @ index-HS5-14da.js:48
Mg @ index-HS5-14da.js:37
jg @ index-HS5-14da.js:37
Rg @ index-HS5-14da.js:37
lc @ index-HS5-14da.js:37
fh @ index-HS5-14da.js:37
(anonymous) @ index-HS5-14da.js:37
tu @ index-HS5-14da.js:40
zd @ index-HS5-14da.js:37
As @ index-HS5-14da.js:37
ja @ index-HS5-14da.js:37
Gg @ index-HS5-14da.js:37
index-HS5-14da.js:48 TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at r (index-HS5-14da.js:48:9155)
    at Object.Mg (index-HS5-14da.js:37:9855)
    at jg (index-HS5-14da.js:37:10009)
    at Rg (index-HS5-14da.js:37:10066)
    at lc (index-HS5-14da.js:37:31439)
    at fh (index-HS5-14da.js:37:31856)
    at index-HS5-14da.js:37:36768
    at tu (index-HS5-14da.js:40:36808)
    at zd (index-HS5-14da.js:37:8991)
    at As (index-HS5-14da.js:37:33142)
```

Comment: How is it `not working`?

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It says on my site that a secure connection cannot be established. The redirection to https doesn't happen on my site.

Comment: You send a self signed certificate.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and think about your approach. Dump your self-signed. SIgn up with cloudflare, use their free service. Get a backend certificate from them and let them handle the front end side. Fater, your IP is not exposed, and stuff like this redirect are just a setting in their proxy.

Comment: Is mod_ssl, mod_socache_shmcb, mod_rewrite, and mod_headers enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Uh... I am a little rusty in Apache, but I believe this is the part that garbles up:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
                                       ^
                                      / \
```

As in there is missing a `/`, so the rule becomes `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]?`

As far as I recall `$1` contains whatever relative url was called on original site say `foo/bar` and the redirected URL therefore becomes invalid due to missing `/` between domain name and relative URL.

Comment: No, this is fine. Your example would end up with a double `/`.

Comment: So what would the issue be? Do I need to buy a certificate? Is this a self signed one and is a self signed certificaten  not enough?

Comment: Self signed is not the problem ... or it could be depending on the error in the brower. If it is self signed and the browser does not trust the certificate then you should be able to choose "continue" in the browser to see the encrypted site. But if the browser is complaining about URL does not exists then it is a redirect issue. One thing I notice in example above is there is no `DocumentRoot` for the secured site?

Comment: When I go on the site normally on Chrome I can access it (with the not secure warning in the url bar - I uploaded a screenshot of it in my original post), I think on Firefox the warning is there with the option to continue. I hosted the application on with godaddy hosting, not on my vps so I tought that the DocumentRoot would not work. Is that correct or am I mistaken?

Comment: Ok the "nicht sicher" (en: "Not safe" for the non german speakers) just means that the Firefox browser does not trust the self signed certificate. This is not an error with Apache configuration. It works as intended. Hint: Note that the browser address starts with `https://`. If you used a Let's Encrypt certificate instead of self signed then your browser would not complain, since it trust certificates issued by Let's Encrypt.